# Delete duplicate records on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with duplicate records, where I've already created a script to summarize the duplicate records with the original ones, but I'm not able to delete the duplicate records.

I'm trying this way:

```
DELETE FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
WHERE COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO IN (SELECT MAX(COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO) COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO 
                              FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
                              GROUP BY COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO)
```

The idea was to take the last record of each `COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO` and delete it, but this way all the records are being deleted, what am I doing wrong?

The table is structured as follows:

[image]

I need to delete, for example, the second record of `COD_MOVIMENTO = 405` with `COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO = 9`, there should only be one record of `COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO` different in each `COD_MOVIMENTO`

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: So you want to delete only the last record or all but one? How do you decide which to keep of each group? What are you grouping by, `COD_MOVIMENTO` and `COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO` or just `COD_MOVIMENTO`, it''s not clear?

Comment: What I need at this point is the following, there are some duplicate records, for example the one in the photo where I have two identical records, with the same COD_MOVIMENTO = 405, the same COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO = 9 and the same VAL_TOTAL_APURADO, I need to delete one of these records and leave only one, in those cases where there is duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE with row-numbering to calculate which rows to delete.

You may need to adjust the partitioning and ordering clauses, it's not clear exactly what you need.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COD_MOVIMENTO, COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO mp
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your delete statement will take the max() but even if you have only one record, it'll return a value.

Also note that your group by should be on COD_MOVIMENTO.

As a fix, make sure there are at least two items:

```
DELETE FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
WHERE COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO IN 
(SELECT MAX(COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO)COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO 
FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
WHERE cod_plano_pagamento in 
(select cod_plano_pagamento 
  from TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO 
  group by COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
  having count(*) > 1)
GROUP BY COD_MOVIMENTO )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you want remove duplicate rows with same COD_MOVIMENTO, COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO and VAL_TOTAL_APURADO, try this:

```
delete f1 from 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COD_MOVIMENTO, COD_PLANO_PAGAMENTO, VAL_TOTAL_APURADO ORDER BY COD_MOVIMENTO) rang
    FROM TB_MOVIMENTO_PDV_DETALHE_PLANO_PAGAMENTO
) f1
where f1.rang>1
```